# How to solve $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+\sin x}{x-\sin x}$ using L'Hopital rule

Tags: limits

It is required to find limit using L'Hopital rule

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x+\sin x}{x-\sin x}$$

first I tried using L'Hopital rule right away, which gives us

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}$$

playing with this a bit I managed to get it to the form of

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-\cos x}$$

I don't know how to move further. Did I do something wrong in previous steps or am I on the right path?

Comment: You cannot directly apply L'Hospital's rule as discussed in this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4154211/problem-applying-lhopitals-rule/

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1+\cos x}{1-\cos x}$ does not exist. This can be much easier be solved *without* L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: Divide both numerator and denominator by $x$ ...